# Laravel Tinker Error when creating user data

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use tinker to create dummy user in table but it is showing the below error. Can any one please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance

```
php artisan tinker
  
User::factory()->count(5)->create()
```

Error:

> Aliasing 'User' to 'App\Notifications\User' for this Tinker session.
> Call to undefined method User::factory() in Psy Shell code on line 1

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Have you multiples `class User` in different `namespace` ? If so, start your tinker commande with an `use` or the complete `namespace`'s path.

Answer (score 3):

"*Aliasing 'User' to 'App\Notifications\User' for this Tinker session.*" You seem to have a Notification named `User`. Notifications don't have factories, you'd want to use your Model instead.

Use
`\App\Models\User::factory()->count(5)->create()`

Answer (score 0):

The error message obviously says it`s because of wrong class file requirement.
Use the right namespace for your model.

Probably:

```
\App\Models\User
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that tinker cant find no User on `App\Notification\User`** so you choose a directory by urself which I suppose is in `\App\Models\User`

In stead of using `User::factory()->count(5)->create()`

Use `\App\Models\User::factory()->count(5)->create()`

**This one works for me !**